# GuildMemberJoin PN Message

Tags: java, discord-jda

Hey I want to send a welcome message to new people.
This is my Code. Im very new at Java please help me to get this feature working:

```
package de.backxtar.listener;

import java.time.OffsetDateTime;

import net.dv8tion.jda.api.EmbedBuilder;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.entities.Member;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.events.guild.member.GuildMemberJoinEvent;
import net.dv8tion.jda.api.hooks.ListenerAdapter;

public class JoinListener extends ListenerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void onGuildMemberJoin(GuildMemberJoinEvent event) {
        Member member = event.getMember();

        if((event.getGuild().getDefaultChannel()) != null) {

            EmbedBuilder builder = new EmbedBuilder();

            builder.setColor(0xf22613);
            builder.setThumbnail("http://image.png");
            builder.setTitle("Willkommen auf Da Hood!");
            builder.setFooter("Powered by Backxtar.");
            builder.setTimestamp(OffsetDateTime.now());
            builder.setDescription("Herzlich willkommen" + member.getAsMention() + "auf **Da Hood**!\n"
                    + "[**Da Hood - The Best Gaming-Discord!**](https://xyz.gg)");

            member.getUser().openPrivateChannel().queue((ch) -> {
                ch.sendMessage(builder.build()).queue();
            });
        }
    }
}
```

How does this funktion to be? `if((event.getGuild().getDefaultChannel()) != null) {`

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

first of all, `event.getGuild().getDefaultChannel()` returns you the channel set for "*System Messages Channel*" in the server settings, or if none is set there, the first text channel on the Discord Server.

Secondly, unfortunately I cannot tell you why your code does not work because it works perfectly for me, maybe it could be because your Discord server does not have **TextChannel** if that is the case try if your code works when you create a **TextChannel** on your Discord server.